# Facet Wrap stat_compare_means() with 'free_y' - r, ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, visualization, facet

I have no simple way of creating a reproducible example due to the size and complexity of the dataset I'm working with, to which I apologize.

I am using `stat_compare_means()` to add the results of hypothesis testing to `geom_boxplot()`, which works well when creating a single plot. Using the following code:

```
p <- ggplot(smeaneps, aes(x=factor(Period,level=order), y=average,fill=Period)) +
  geom_boxplot() + 
  geom_jitter(color="black", size=0.8, alpha=0.4) +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette="Set1",breaks=order) +
  ggtitle("Average Episode Count - Pre and Post Pandemic Lockdown") +
  ylab("Average Episode Count") + xlab("Period") +
  theme_apa() 

p + stat_compare_means(comparisons = list(c("Pre","Post")),method = "t.test") + 
    stat_compare_means( aes(label = ..p.signif..), 
                        label.x = 1.5, label.y = 0.98,method = "t.test") +
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

Where I'm running into a problem is combing charts using `facet_wrap()`, each chart has a different scale so the `label = ..p.signif..` is all over the place. See below:

```
bp <- ggplot(sbehs, aes(x=factor(Period, level=order), y=average, fill=Period)) + 
  geom_boxplot(aes(fill=Target)) +
  ggtitle("Average Episode Count - Individual Behaviors") +
  ylab("Average Episode Count") + xlab("Period") +
  theme_apa()
# Split in horizontal direction
bp + stat_compare_means(comparisons = list(c("Pre","Post")),method = "t.test") + 
    stat_compare_means( aes(label = ..p.signif..), 
                        label.x = 1.5, label.y = 0.75,method = "t.test") +
  theme(legend.position = "none") +
  facet_wrap(. ~ Target,scales='free',ncol=2)
```

[image]

Is there a loop like method that would allow me to enter separate `label.y` for each facet? Something like:

```
for i in c(0.75,1.1,0.75,4.5){
bp + stat_compare_means(comparisons = list(c("Pre","Post")),method = "t.test") + 
    stat_compare_means( aes(label = ..p.signif..), 
                        label.x = 1.5, label.y = i,method = "t.test") +
  theme(legend.position = "none") +
  facet_wrap(. ~ Target,scales='free',ncol=2) 
}
```

Or something a little simpler, that's just to get the concept across. For bonus points, could you also tell me why the p-values are clipping at the top... :/

Comment: Would something like this suffice as the start of a reproducible example? `data("ToothGrowth"); ToothGrowth$segment = ToothGrowth$len < 20; ggboxplot(ToothGrowth, x = "supp", y = "len", color = "supp", palette = "npg", add = "jitter") + stat_compare_means() + facet_wrap(~segment)` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to this, instead of trying to set the height of each individual `label.y` you simply need to use the `vjust` attribute to adjust the position of the label.

Note `vjust = 1` in the following code snippet:

```
p + stat_compare_means( aes(label = ..p.signif..), 
                        label.x = 1.5, vjust = 1, method = "t.test") +
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```